# Show invariance of $\mu$ under $t$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Given $\mu(B)=\int_B fdm_2,    B \in \Bbb{B}_2$,  with $f(x)$ = $1\over|det(A)|$$f(A^{-1}(x-b))$,  and $m_2$ the Lebesgue measure on $\Bbb{R}^2$.

Futhermore, we have $t(\mu)=\hat{f}\cdot m_2$, where $\hat{f}(x)=\frac{1}{|det(A)|}f\circ t^{-1}(x)= \frac{1}{|det(A)|}$$f(A^{-1}(x-b))  $

$\mathbf{problem}$:

Assume $f(x)=g(x^Tx)$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}^2$. Show that if $A$ is orthonormal, and $b=0$, then $\mu$ is invariant under $t$, i.e. $t(\mu)=\mu$

I would appreciate some help getting started. I can't figure out how $f(x)=g(x^Tx)$ helps me here. I know, since A is orthonormal, $|det(A)|=1$, and $x^{T}x =(A^{-1}x)^TA^{-1}x$, which reduces both $f$, but I can't don't know how to procede from here. Is it useful to know that $m_2$ is translation invariant?

Comment: You can start by straightening out your symbolism. Your formula for $f$ in the first line involves $f$ on both sides. Your definition of $\hat f$ is identical to the formula for $f$, making $\hat f \equiv f$. You use $t$ without defining it (either that, or you defined it as a function on a domain of set functions, but then turn around and immediately expect it's inverse to be composed with $f$, indicating it is defined on $\Bbb R^2$ without any explanation). What exactly is the dot operation in $\hat f \cdot m_2$?